# determining if a graph is a tree using map

Tags: c++, graph, dictionary, tree

**The Problem** : I am given an undirected graph with nodes count(n),number of edges(m) and the edges between nodes. I need to determine whether it is a tree or not using **std::map**.

**the input** will be like this :
n m

then m lines describing edges between nodes

so I tried the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,int> Links;
    int n,m,Parent,Child;

    cin>>n>>m;
    if(m!=n-1) //First Condition -> Number of Links=Number of Nodes-1 -> No loops && No Cuts
    {
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    while(m!=0)
    {
        m--;
        cin>>Parent>>Child;


        if(Links[Child]!=0)
        {
            if(Links[Parent]!=0) //No node has more than one parent
            {
                cout<<"NO"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            Links[Parent]=Child;
        }
        else
        Links[Child]=Parent;

    }
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but it just produces wrong answers and I don't know why(I tested it on this online judge's problem [A similar problem on SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Y/))

Any help would be appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. For instance 1->2, 2->3, 3->1 is not a tree, because it has a cycle, but your code would print YES. To test if a graph is a tree you need to look for cycles, if a graph has a cycle it's not a tree. This is a more complicated algorithm than you have. Look it up on the net, I'm sure you can find examples.

Comment: it will print NO as u have to enter number of nodes and edges first before entering those inputs so the input in the first line will be : 3 3 and I will check if "3(m here)!=3(n here)-1" which is true so it will print NO before u try to input the graph ... and I don't think I need to check for cycles here because if there is a cycle, there must be either one or more edges than expected(ie:m!=n-1) or a cut somewhere else in the graph and I think the two conditions "m==n-1" and "no node have more than one parent" is enough to point that out.

Comment: Yes you are right, I misinterpreted your algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found what is wrong .

the problem is when there is a loop and separated nodes in the graph. It can't detect them I tried input like :
5 4
1 2
3 1
2 4
4 3
which is a graph with a loop and separated node and it output "YES"
but if I entered it that way it output "NO":
5 4
1 2
1 3
2 4
3 4
so generally, I need to check for cuts in the graph .

**EDIT:** I changed the idea to this and it is now working as expected :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,bool> Links;
    int n,m,N1,N2;

    cin>>n>>m;
    if(m!=n-1) //First Condition: Number of Links=Number of Nodes-1 
    {
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    while(m!=0)
    {
        m--;
        cin>>N1>>N2;

        if(Links[N1] && Links[N2]) //Asumming the graph is given as it builds
        {
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
       Links[N1]=1;
       Links[N2]=1;
    }


    cout<<"YES"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```